# How to change the record when mapped to a different column

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've a column which has unique ID alpha-numeric with name PLANT_ID
Eg: AUTO-10784-28
I've another column with name PACKAGE_ID which has AUTO107842802.I would like to display the value in result column PACKAGE_ID as AUTO-10784-28-02. Also, sometimes there won't be last two digits in the PACKAGE_ID then the result should be same as PLANT_ID only but with two zeros added like AUTO-10784-28-00. I've tried using STUFF() and LTRIM but it didn't work. I don't have any idea on how to solve this. Please help.

Comment: So what are the rules you want to apply to the PACKAGE_ID column to produce the format you require?

Comment: Hi @NickW I want to add '-' after Alphabets and also after 5 digits and after 2 digits and after this if there are any other extra digits I want to trim them to two digits only. and in case there are no digits I want to add two 0. I tried STUFF() but could add only at one place

Comment: Are there always going to be at least 5 digits? If there are only 6 digits do you want to add a single 0 to the end? Are there always going to be 4 alphas at the start or could it be any number? Are the alphas always just a-z or could they have other characters in them e.g. AU8TO or AU£TO?

Comment: Yes alphabets are going to be 4 always and no special character will be there. Also the no. of digits may vary. But, finally there should be '-' after the alphabets and after 5 digits and again after two digits. So now total characters are 11 (includes alphabets and numbers) and if there are no more characters left there should be two zeros added after the Third '-' and in case if there are more number of digits after the third '-' the number of digits should be trimmed to two digits

Comment: Also, adding to the actual question, if I've values like (AUTO123474, PORT6283318, DOC82647197) how can I add '-' after the alphabets and after 4 digits and after 2 digits and add 0 if no digits are left. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT
CASE length(PACKAGE_ID)
WHEN 9 THEN LEFT(PACKAGE_ID,4)||'-'||RIGHT(PACKAGE_ID,5)||'-00'
WHEN 10 THEN LEFT(PACKAGE_ID,4)||'-'||SUBSTR(PACKAGE_ID,5,5)||'-'||RIGHT(PACKAGE_ID,1)||'0'
ELSE LEFT(PACKAGE_ID,4)||'-'||SUBSTR(PACKAGE_ID,5,5)||'-'||RIGHT(PACKAGE_ID,2)
END CALC_PACKAGE_ID
FROM TEST_DATA_SO
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. In case I have three values (AUTO-12345-678-02 , AUTO-2674-8728-1 , AUTO-756294-553- ) I want to eliminate the characters after the last - (including -) how can I do it?

Comment: Also, adding to the actual question, if I've values like (AUTO123474, PORT6283318, DOC82647197) how can I add '-' after the alphabets and after 4 digits and after 2 digits and add 0 if no digits are left. Please help